# Is there a name for the UX pattern where you enter a code from an unauthenticated device on an authenticated one in order to login?

Tags: login, authentication

Several services such as YouTube, Plex, and XFINITY use a pattern in which an unauthenticated device displays a code for the user to enter on an authenticated device. When the user enters the code on their authenticated device, their unauthenticated device is then authenticated.

Is there a name for this pattern? I'd love to learn more about best practices when implementing such a login system.

Here are a few screenshots of the process I'm talking about:
[image: YouTube Device Pairing Screen]
[image: Plex Device Pairing Screen]

Comment: I’m glad you posted that picture. From what you were describing, I thought you were describing 2-factor authentication; but I think this would count as something else.

Comment: I don't think this has a specific name, it's a form of authentication UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's called [Cross Platform Authentication](https://tech.ebu.ch/groups/CPA) and is a technology originally developed by [EBU](https://tech.ebu.ch/home) to interconnect devices and platforms. While development of CPA started around 2013 by BBC, it was approved by [ETSI](https://portal.etsi.org/webapp/WorkProgram/Report_WorkItem.asp?WKI_ID=47970) in 2016

[image]

## CPA flow

**Regular:**

[image]

**Single Sign-On**

[image]

[**CPA Project PDF**](https://tech.ebu.ch/docs/tech/tech3366.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Back In the old days there was dedicated device to generate this code: [Security_token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_token)

Some companies name for the token generator app:

- Steam call it: [Steam Guard Mobile Authenticator](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4440-RTUI-9218)
- Google calls it: [Google Authenticator](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1066447?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)
- Microsoft: [Microsoft Authenticator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/multi-factor-authentication/end-user/microsoft-authenticator-app-how-to)

I think there is no buzzword for this technology (yet). I would call it "token based authentication", and call part of the site or the app "Authenticator".

Comment: Those apps are a different pattern though. They're part of multi-factor based authentication using time-based one-time passwords, the implications of which are different from the methods used by Plex and YouTube. For instance, Google Authenticator requires a user to setup the app using a secret key, which is then used to compute the password with the current timestamp. Neither YouTube nor Plex require this setup, so implementing it securely would require different approaches.

Comment: Agree they are part of the 2-factor authentication, when you try to login from new device. 2 factor auth: 1st step give your username and password, and login with the token. Plex skip the 1st step, and add new device just with the token.